# Android Left Right Channel

Tags: android, audio

is it possible to reserve left channel/ speaker for our application and leave the right untouched programatically?

The idea is to use left channel for sending audio serial commands while the right channel can still be used for normal sound output.

Comment: Are you looking to change the behavior in just your app or you want other apps to not be able to play sound through the left speaker?

Comment: yes this behaviour is only present when my application is running. I want all other applications to use the right channel while my app has an unused left channel to send the audio serial output.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the APIs, specifically http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html and
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html
but I couldn't find anything.

My guess is if you want to do something like that you'll probably have to use the android NDK http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html and if you want to disable the left channel totally, you'll probably need root access.